# NFC card reader which can communicate with a mobile device

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

Hi can anyone suggest me a NFC card reader whose sdk is available and using that we can communicate with the mobile device and transfer data scanned by the reader.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

[ACR 122U](http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/) is a good solution with SDK. I used it in both android phone and desktop. Host Card Emulation mode is also supported by this device.